# Sum Row From Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am running a SQL Query and returning the results to a gridview.  I want to display the Totals in the footer row of the gridview.  Everything works perfect,e xcept for a column that I am formatting as a % in the gridview.  This is how I format it as a percetage

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="percentage" HeaderText="P" DataFormatString="{0:P}" />
```

And it throws the error message of:

> input string was not in correct format

This is how I am calling it

```
protected void analysispack1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (analysispack1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        decimal showit = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in analysispack1.Rows)
        {
            showit += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].Text);
        }
        try { analysispack1.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = tmpDailAttendance.ToString(); }
        catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in analysispack1.Rows)
{
    showit += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].Text.Replace("%", string.Empty));
}
```